# How to achieve conversion from List<SomeParamType> to List<SomeParamType<?>>

Tags: java, generics

While using Spring ApplicationContext and its method `getBeansOfType` I have run into an issue with generic types. This demonstrates the problem:

```
class Test
{
  List<Generator<?>> allGenerators = 
      new ArrayList(getBeansOfType(Generator.class).values()); // Raw type warning 
                                                               // for new ArrayList()
  <T> Map<String, T> getBeansOfType(Class<T> klass) {
    return emptyMap();
  }
}

interface Generator<R> {}
```

I retrieve all beans of a parameterized type from the container. I want to have them as `Generator<?>` and use custom logic to safely cast to the appropriate type parameter based on a property on each `Generator` instance.

My problem is that I can't find any way to assign to `allGenerators` without type safety warnings, even though on a conceptual level I am not committing to any unchecked type parameter. I just want to convert a raw type to a wildcard type.

Is there any idiom which does not require `@SuppressWarnings` to get there?

Answer (score 3):

Not actually a conversion, but a program that builds a list of the required type without warnings:

```
public List<Generator<?>> solution() {
    List<Generator<?>> dst = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Generator<?> g : getBeansOfType(Generator.class).values()) {
        dst.add(g);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: But that clearly gives a "raw type" warning on `Generator g`. You can disable that warning in Eclipse, but that's not what I'm aiming at.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it seems ok if I use `Generator<?>` as the type of `g` (at least, the code compiles and I don't get any warning)

Comment: You have to enable -Xlint:unchecked in the compiler settings in IntelliJ to see the warning, or compile it manually with this setting enabled.

Comment: You could iterate over a collection of `Object` and then do a `dst.add((Generator<?>) g)` and you would avoid the unchecked warning.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinDalorzo. I added the flag, but still can't get any warning from Intellij (note I updated the code some minutes ago)

Comment: You're right this version does not generate the warning.

Comment: Copying into `ArrayList` is more of a coincidence in my code. Suppose I just had `Collection<Generator<?>> allGenerators = getBeansOfType(Generator.class).values();`, then this approach would force me to copy stuff at runtime just to avoid a warning at compile time. On the other hand, if the "raw type" warning is not by specification, but only introduced by "lint"-kind of checks, then my question is weakened. My primary aim was to meet the promise of Generics that "my code is type-safe as long as I don't get any unchecked warnings".

Comment: BTW in your code, and without the "raw type" warning, you can even write `for (Generator<String> g : getBeansOfType(...))` with no complaints from the compiler. That's why it makes little sense to me to factor out that warning.

Comment: Well, I thought this were more of a puzzle than a real world requirement. `@SuppressWarning` is really the only way to go without library support (`getBeansOfType` should be paired with a method that works with type tokens)

Comment: The `Generator<String>` example causes a plain compiler warning, no need for lint

Comment: Interesting, I don't get any. What warning do you get, maybe this one is IntelliJ-specific?

Comment: Standard javac [output](http://hastebin.com/ijunitihey.tex), [source code](http://hastebin.com/casuzuloca.xml)

Comment: I see. So the current conclusion is that standard `javac` allows conversion from raw type to wildcard type, but doesn't allow the same thing to happen to a nested wildcard type.

Comment: I wouldn't use those words, because they contains two rules when one is enough. `Generator` is a raw type and can be safely converted to `Generator<?>`. `List<Generator>` is not a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8), and that's why the conversion is illegal

Comment: But it's a raw type parameter and it isn't allowed to be converted to a wildcard type parameter, the latter making use of nested wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's not possible (to convert a raw type to an one with a wildcard parameter).

The reason is that the *generic type* (and in particular, the wildcard) is something different than a *class type* and cannot be represented with the tools of class types.